# sqrt() pow() fabs() do not work

Tags: c++, math, c++03

i am trying to compile my program where i am using the functions like sqrt pow and fabs. I do have math.h included but for some reason i get errors like:

```
    error C2668: 'fabs' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
```

same for the rest of the functions
i have this included:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "math.h"
```

i tried including but still same errors.
Does anyone know why they are not being recognized?
my file is .cpp not .c but it is an MFC project.

thanks

Comment: Are you using two different Calls for the Same Function?

Comment: Removed the "C" tag, as this does not involve the C language.

Comment: You should include the actual code that triggered the error. With just the error description what you will get is someone telling you that *ambiguous call* means that the compiler could not make up its mind and decide which is best among two overloads...

Comment: Another question of many where either [karthik](http://stackoverflow.com/users/644073/karthik) or [user692270](http://stackoverflow.com/users/692270/user692270) accepts @karthik 's answer. Stop this faked upvote-farming.

Comment: Added the C++03 tag as this has been fixed in C++11. It's now overloaded for all arithmetic types. Note that using `fabs` (floating point abs) on integers is a bad idea. Use `std::abs` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because those functions are overloaded for several types: float, double and long double. Thus, if you pass in an integer, the compiler doesn't which one to choose. An easy fix is to simply pass a double (or multiply what you pass in by 1.0), this should fix the problem.

```
      int value = rand();
      int result1 = (int)fabs(value*1.0); 
      printf("%d, %d\n", result1, result1);
```

otherwise:

```
     int value = rand();
     int result1 = (int)fabs((double)value); 
     printf("%d, %d\n", result1, result1);
```

Comment: Adding 0.0 is better than multiplying by 1.0.

Comment: `static_cast` is much better than multiplying by `1.0`, because it makes the code clear.

Comment: @Mark: Either way, the compiler won't actually do any arithmetic. But @Kirill is exactly right.

Comment: @kirill:in both Way the compiler does the same thing

Comment: @Kirill: I say compiler optimization is same for both the cases.I think you misunderstood my comment.

Comment: Or you could use std::abs, which has an overload for int.

Comment: Another question of many where either [karthik](http://stackoverflow.com/users/644073/karthik) or [user692270](http://stackoverflow.com/users/692270/user692270) accepts @karthik 's answer. Stop this faked upvote-farming.

Comment: Using `fabs` on `rand` function? Weird! `abs` would convert negative to positive, but `rand` will always give `>=0`